# when use autofac accoure this error : : 'ConfigureServices returning an System.IServiceProvider isn't supported.'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, autofac

i wqant ot use the autofac in my project .

i  write this startup :

```
  public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly())
                .AsImplementedInterfaces();
        builder.Populate(services);
        builder.AddDispatchers();

        var conteiner = builder.Build();

        return new AutofacServiceProvider(conteiner);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

nad this is my program.cs :

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
     .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
     .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webHostBuilder =>
     {
         webHostBuilder
          .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
          .UseIISIntegration()
          .UseStartup<Startup>();
     })
     .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

but it show me this errro :

> 'ConfigureServices returning an System.IServiceProvider isn't supported.'

How can is solve this problem?

Comment: @vasily.sib in `Program`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are trying the pre 3.0 way. [Check the ConfigureServices docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.startupbase.configureservices?view=aspnetcore-3.1). It does not supprot the `IServiceProvider` return type.

```
public virtual void ConfigureServices (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection services);
```

From the autofac docs:

> This is not for ASP.NET Core 3+ or the .NET Core 3+ generic hosting support - ASP.NET Core 3 has deprecated the ability to return a service provider from ConfigureServices

Check [Autofac net core guide](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html) post 3.0

```
public class Program
{
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    // ASP.NET Core 3.0+:
    // The UseServiceProviderFactory call attaches the
    // Autofac provider to the generic hosting mechanism.
    var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webHostBuilder => {
          webHostBuilder
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
        })
        .Build();

    host.Run();
  }
}
```

```
public class Startup
{
  public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
  {
    // In ASP.NET Core 3.0 `env` will be an IWebHostingEnvironment, not IHostingEnvironment.
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    this.Configuration = builder.Build();
  }

  public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; private set; }

  public ILifetimeScope AutofacContainer { get; private set; }

  // ConfigureServices is where you register dependencies. This gets
  // called by the runtime before the ConfigureContainer method, below.
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
    // Add services to the collection. Don't build or return
    // any IServiceProvider or the ConfigureContainer method
    // won't get called.
    services.AddOptions();
  }

  // ConfigureContainer is where you can register things directly
  // with Autofac. This runs after ConfigureServices so the things
  // here will override registrations made in ConfigureServices.
  // Don't build the container; that gets done for you by the factory.
  public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
  {
    // Register your own things directly with Autofac, like:
    builder.RegisterModule(new MyApplicationModule());
  }

  // Configure is where you add middleware. This is called after
  // ConfigureContainer. You can use IApplicationBuilder.ApplicationServices
  // here if you need to resolve things from the container.
  public void Configure(
    IApplicationBuilder app,
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
  {
    // If, for some reason, you need a reference to the built container, you
    // can use the convenience extension method GetAutofacRoot.
    this.AutofacContainer = app.ApplicationServices.GetAutofacRoot();

    loggerFactory.AddConsole(this.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();
    app.UseMvc();
  }
}
```

Comment: i use that but it not wirk

Comment: Please be more specific on why it does not work, so that I can help a bit more.

Comment: please see the repostiroy .

Comment: Your repository uses the solution you describe in the question. This will not work. You need to totally restructure your code, using the post 3.0 autofac configuration way.

Comment: It's an example of a module you need injected. You need to create your own.